# Could not initialize class twitter4j.TwitterFactory cause by NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: noclassdeffounderror, twitter4j

I know the problem is `NoClassDefFoundError` when I build `TwitterFactory` form `ConfigurationBuilder` like this from RMI call:

```
    ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder().setHttpProxyHost("58.215.173.23").setHttpProxyPort(8580).setOAuthConsumerKey("18aVBaTUUx5Axh1WgBe7w").setOAuthConsumerSecret("RhE83B9RML060mfMT2FVpD0O6V7wZxZnax1RCA3Y4");
    TwitterFactory tf = new TwitterFactory(cb.build());
    twitter = tf.getInstance();
```

But the debugger did't tells me what class is missing.I even cannot catch this exception,it just goes wrong.

I got those information by add breakpoint at `ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ...`,and it stops at

```
public InvocationTargetException(Throwable target) {
    super((Throwable)null);  // Here
    this.target = target;
}
```

in `InvocationTargetException` class, and I cannot get stacktrace also.

Please help me to find out what is probably missing or I did something wrong.